# How does stacking [Element] Aura work?

Tags: shadowrun-sr4

The `[Element] Aura` spell (Street Magic 173) provides the target with a bonus to the DV of melee attacks equal to the caster's hits, makes the attacks treated as that type of damage, and resisted with half impact armor.

What happens if you have more than one type of aura on you at once?  Do the DV bonuses stack? Does it count as all the types of damage for purposes of resistance (so 2 fire resist and 2 cold resist would give you +4), or just the best, or just the worst?  What happens if the melee attack already has AP on it?

Comment: I was playing around with concepts, and ended up with a character sustaining 3-4 of these auras via foci and dual-wielding monofilament whips...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is specified a couple of pages before the spell (Street Magic p161):

> Note that spell effects may sometimes create modifiers that add on to existing modifiers from gear, implants, or adept powers. Unless stated otherwise, these effects are cumulative (though the gamemaster can always rule otherwise). **Spell effects do not stack on top of other spell effects, however—only the strongest effect applies.**

Note that even though spell *effects* don't stack, spells themselves do. So there is nothing preventing you from having a fire and ice aura at the same time. Another interesting point regarding Element Spells (Street Magic p162):

> A spell may have more than one elemental effect—each effect adds a +2 Drain modifier, and the elemental effects are combined (though in some cases they may cancel out).

Then, applying it to your questions:

**What happens if you have more than one type of aura on you at once? Do the DV bonuses stack?**

Nope, as they are both spell effects.

**Does it count as all the types of damage for purposes of resistance (so 2 fire resist and 2 cold resist would give you +4), or just the best, or just the worst?**

This one is tricky. Technically, you have both spells at the same time. Your attacks can't be Fire and Ice at the same time, as that would require a "[Fire & Ice] Aura" with a +2 Drain. However, it is safe to assume that you could switch between Fire Attacks and Ice Attacks at will.

If you actually use a "[Fire & Ice] Aura" with a +2 Drain, the effects are combined, meaning you apply them both. Then, Insulation and Fire Resistance would both apply (better use different elements!).

**What happens if the melee attack already has AP on it?**

It stacks if the AP doesn't come from a spell effect.

Comment: Thanks.  I knew there had to be *something* to prevent getting crazy DV bonuses from it.  One more question, though - would the "Half impact" be applied before or after the AP from the weapon?

Comment: @Bobson Before. "You resist with half Impact armor", meaning the attack is resisted with a value of half the impact, from which the AP is deducted. So yes, it hurts :)

Comment: Excellent.  This character may not do the absolutely crazy damage I was sure was wrong, but he's still going to be very deadly... Thanks again!

Comment: @Bobson if you go the Dual-element route, there can be some reall funny combinations: A Force 6 [Water+Blast] Aura will Knock Down anything with less than 12 in Body automatically...

Comment: That leads to some really weird questions...  What happens if you do [Metal+Smoke]?  Maybe I should make that into a whole new question...  **Edit:** Actually, come to think of it, there's no limit on the number you can stack, for +2 Drain each.  That can get *really* weird

Answer (score 1):

IIRC 4e policy on stacking bonuses is "stacks, unless explicitly stated otherwise" (digging for the right quotes for that). The spells do not stack, though, as explicitly stated on p161 of *Street Magic* (see @Mikalichov 's answer)

So, in order

- DV bonuses do not stack, the highest applies.
- The type with the highest DV bonus (so one resistance type only).
- Can't find anything specific about it, unfortunately; my call is AP applying to halved impact armor.

Comment: Well, it is actually 'explicitly stated' that spell effects don't stack :)

Comment: thx, I stand corrected.